# How to advance to a newpage with printdocument in .NET?

Tags: .net, delphi-prism, printdocument, oxygene

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does Hasmorepages PrintPageEventArgs property do exactly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544989/what-does-hasmorepages-printpageeventargs-property-do-exactly)

I would like to advance my printing to a newpage without leaving the print event.

So far, what I found out is that you can't and you have to leave print event. Then, call it again for a newpage.

If that is true, is there a workaround where you can tell the printer or the printdocument to start printing on a newpage without having to leave the print event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. As you see in your [other related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11544989/62576), the proper way to do this is to set the `PrintPageEventArgs.HasMorePages` property to `True`, and then start the next page when the event is called again.