# What does Hasmorepages PrintPageEventArgs property do exactly?

Tags: .net, printing, delphi-prism, printdocument

I am trying to understand what Hasmorepages PrintPageEventArgs property is, why would you use it and how does it work.

MSDN Library doesn't really have a good explanation. All they say is that if you set it to true, printpage event is called again. Is that mean the event loops on itself without leaving or leaves and calls itself again or relies on you to call the printpage event again?

I am just trying to understand PrintPageEventArgs.hasmorepages property. Any hints or help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HasMorePages` is a boolean property of the `PrintPageEventArgs` you receive as a parameter of the event. You set it to `True` after printing the current page if there are more pages to be printed, or `False` if the current page is the last one.

Events are always called for you by something in the framework, and are never supposed to be called directly by you. They are *events*, which mean they're dispatched to tell you that something has happened and give you a chance to respond or  react.

If you set it to `True`, the `PrintPage` event is called again automatically; you do not call it yourself. (That's exactly what the MSDN documentation says: If you set it to true, the printpage event **is called again**. It doesn't say *you'll need to call it again* - it says *is called again*.)

```
ev.HasMorePages := DoYouHaveMorePagesToPrint;
```

For a VB.NET example of the event and how to use `ev.HasMorePages`, see the [MSDN documentation for PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=VS.71%29.aspx). For info on `PrintPageEventArgs`, see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), which has a link to the [members of PrintPageEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs_members%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (including `HasMorePages`).

Answer (score 4):

It is not a property of a PrintDocument, it is a property of PrintPageEventArgs.  An instance of which gets passed to your PrintPage event handler.

The way the PrintController and PrintDocument classes work is heavily affected by the way printing is implemented in Windows.  A core implementation detail is that it is *page-based*.  The printer driver deals with one page at a time, the underlying winapi function is StartPage().  Anything rendered to the print device context ends up on one page.  Then the EndPage() winapi function completes the page and submits it to the spooler.

It might help to diagram the calls made while a 3 page document is printed:

```
StartDoc()
    PrintDocument.BeginPrint event
    StartPage()
       PrintDocument.PrintPage event, e.HasMorePages = true
    EndPage()
    StartPage()
       PrintDocument.PrintPage event, e.HasMorePages = true
    EndPage()
    StartPage()
       PrintDocument.PrintPage event, e.HasMorePages = false
    EndPage()
    PrintDocument.EndPrint event
EndDoc()
```

It ought to be clear now, by assigning e.HasMorePage = true, you let the PrintController keep firing the PrintPage event.  It is up to you to paginate your document and render the content of the correct page in your PrintPage event handler.  You'll need the BeginPrint event to, say, set your internal page counter to 0.

Comment: Opps! I mean to say printpageeventargs not printdocument.

Comment: that's how it should work in theory. Apparenly, in C# or Delphi Prism. There seems to be no BeginDoc or StartDoc method, although there is BeginPrint and EndPrint as you pointed out.

Comment: Sigh, they are underlying winapi calls, as pointed out in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Fix pagination problem when printing in C# using HasMorePages.
Explanation about this code: You can add many rows or read from the database to see the result of pagination during printing, for example, I added only two rows to the table manually, which is not paginated because the number of rows is small. Add many rows manually or insert information from the database into the grid view. This is an example:

```
int currentPage = 1;
int rowsPerPage = 36; //Number of rows per page
int rowIndex = 0;

void pdoc_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int x = 5, y = 5; //Drawing start position
        int rowMargin = 0; //Spacing between lines

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dgvHesaab.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing; //Text with more lines in a row.
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40; //40=row height. Text with more lines in a row.

        dgvHesaab.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;

        int rowCount = dgvHesaab.Rows.Count; //Get the number of rows
        int pageCount = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(rowCount) / Convert.ToDouble(rowsPerPage)));

        //Set header content of columns
        for (int j = this.dgvHesaab.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 132, dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height); //132 = width in row
            StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.LightGray, rect);
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
            if (this.dgvHesaab.Columns[j].HeaderText != null)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.dgvHesaab.Columns[j].HeaderText, SystemFonts.DefaultFont, Brushes.Black, rect, sf);
            }
            x += rect.Width;
        }

        x = 5;
        y += dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height + rowMargin;
        //Set the content of the lines
        while (rowIndex < dgvHesaab.Rows.Count)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgvHesaab.Rows[rowIndex];
            if (row.Cells[0].Value != null)
            {
                for (int j = this.dgvHesaab.Columns.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                {
                    DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[j];
                    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(x, y, 132, dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height); //132 = width in row
                    StringFormat sf = new StringFormat();
                    sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, rect);
                    if (cell.Value != null)
                    {
                        e.Graphics.DrawString(cell.Value.ToString(), new Font("Tahoma", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, rect, sf);
                    }
                    x += rect.Width;
                }
                x = 5;
                y += dgvHesaab.Rows[0].Height + rowMargin;
            }
            rowIndex++;

            //Print a new page if necessary
            if (rowIndex % rowsPerPage == 0 || rowIndex == dgvHesaab.Rows.Count)
            {
                e.HasMorePages = (currentPage < pageCount);
                currentPage++;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}

   
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Begin , Adding a row to the gridView(dgvHesaab) 
        ///<summary>
        ///For example, the name of our Grid View is dgvHesaab
        ///Retrieving data from a database or manually inserting data for a row. 
        ///</summary>

        //add row 1
        dgvHesaab.Rows.Add(new object[]
        {
            "Row 1 : Item 1",
            "Row 1 : Item 2",
            "Row 1 : Item 3",
            "Row 1 : Item 4",
            "Row 1 : Item 5",
            "Row 1 : Item 6",
        });

        //add row 2
        dgvHesaab.Rows.Add(new object[]
        {
            "Row 2 : Item 1",
            "Row 2 : Item 2",
            "Row 2 : Item 3",
            "Row 2 : Item 4",
            "Row 2 : Item 5",
            "Row 2 : Item 6",
        });
        //End , Adding a row to the gridView(dgvHesaab)  

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;
        dgvHesaab.DefaultCellStyle.WrapMode = DataGridViewTriState.True;

        dgvHesaab.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.EnableResizing; //Text with more lines in a row.
        dgvHesaab.ColumnHeadersHeight = 40; //40=row height. Text with more lines in a row.

        dgvHesaab.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes;

        //Begin Print
        PrintDialog pDialog = new PrintDialog();
        pDialog.AllowCurrentPage = false;
        pDialog.AllowPrintToFile = false;
        pDialog.AllowSelection = false;
        pDialog.AllowSomePages = false;
        pDialog.PrintToFile = false;
        pDialog.ShowHelp = false;
        pDialog.ShowNetwork = false;
        if (pDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument pdoc = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument();
            pdoc.PrintPage += new System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventHandler(pdoc_PrintPage);
            pdoc.DocumentName = "Print Title";
            pdoc.PrinterSettings = pDialog.PrinterSettings;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings = pDialog.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings;
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins(100, 100, 100, 100);
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize("A4", 827, 1169);
            pdoc.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = false; //Landscape
            //pdoc.PrinterSettings.Copies = 3;
            PrintPreviewDialog printPreviewDialog1 = new PrintPreviewDialog();
            printPreviewDialog1.Document = pdoc;
            pdoc.Print(); //No preview  
            //printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog(); //printPreview
        }
        //End Print
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}
```