# Print 2 Pages in Visual Basic Application

Tags: vb.net

I have a button that prints a Panel and its contents. All working. I just cannot get it to print 2 pages automatically of the same Panel.

Current Code:

```
bmp = New Bitmap(Output.Width, Output.Height)
    Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)
    Output.DrawToBitmap(bmp, Output.ClientRectangle)
    G.Dispose()
    PrintDocument1.Print()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544989/what-does-hasmorepages-printpageeventargs-property-do-exactly

Answer (score 0):

I actually didnt think about it but i was able to make it print 2 pages by simply adding another Printdocument query

```
PrintDocument1.Print()
PrintDocument1.Print()
```

Worked perfectly